# AddEventlistener in js cannot modify the value of the global variable

Tags: javascript

to get audio's lasted time
**AddEventlistener in js cannot modify the value of the global variable**

```
      //get last time
        last_time="";
        var audioElement = new Audio(music.listen_file);
        var duration;
        audioElement.addEventListener("loadedmetadata", function (_event) {
            duration = audioElement.duration;
            var min=Math.floor(duration/60 )
            var sec=Math.floor(duration)%60;
            last_time=min+":"+sec;  
        });
        console.log(last_time);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you actually changed the value, move your `console.log(last_time);` into the callback function you will see the value been changed once the event fired.

```
  last_time="";
        var audioElement = new Audio(music.listen_file);
        var duration;
        audioElement.addEventListener("loadedmetadata", function (_event) {
            duration = audioElement.duration;
            var min=Math.floor(duration/60 )
            var sec=Math.floor(duration)%60;
            last_time=min+":"+sec;  
            console.log(last_time);
        });
```